# comparing a value of a list with other values in the same list with reputation

Tags: python, list, compare

given a list

`a=[3,7,4,2,0]`

i want to compare each element of the list with all elements of the list

so for first number 3, i want it to be compared with 3,7,4,2,0 and if 3 is smaller than or same as the elements adds 1 to a blank list

repeating this step it will give the list of

`b=[3,1,2,4,5]`
which means for first number 3, there are 3 numbers in list a that are smaller than or same as elements of a

what i tried was using itertools.combination to compare, however it does not compare the same reputation.

another way was to using two for loops and make a square matrix to compare, however this does not work (taking too long time to get result)

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Explored three methods

- function counter_method: Modifying code from [Count of greater elements for each element in the Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-greater-elements-for-each-element-in-the-array/)
- function counter_set_method: an improvement to counter_method suggested by tobias_k
- bisect_method: method of tobias_k

**Code**

```
import bisect

def bisect_method(a):
    b = sorted(a)
    return [len(a) - bisect.bisect_left(b, x) for x in a]

def counter_method(arr): 
    # Count of values in array
    cnts = {i:0 for i in range(max(arr)+1)} 
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        cnts[arr[i]] += 1
    
    # Store the sum of cnts of elements 
    # greater than the current eleement 
    cnt_ge = 0
    for k, cnt in reversed(cnts.items()):
        cnts[k] = cnt_ge + cnts[k]
        cnt_ge = cnts[k]
  
    # cnts[arr[k]] has count of greater or equal to
    return [cnts[x] for x in arr]

# Improvement to counter_method
# initialize cnts using set of array values
# as suggested by tobias_k
def counter_set_method(arr): 
        # Count of values in array
        cnts = {i:0 for i in set(arr)} 
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            cnts[arr[i]] += 1
        
        # Store the sum of cnts of elements 
        # greater than the current eleement 
        cnt_ge = 0
        for k, cnt in reversed(cnts.items()):
            cnts[k] = cnt_ge + cnts[k]
            cnt_ge = cnts[k]
      
        # cnts[arr[k]] has count of greater or equal to
        return [cnts[x] for x in arr]
```

**Verification**

Assert not triggered so equivalent results

```
for a in [[3, 7, 4, 2, 0], [3, 7, 4, 2, 0, 4]]:
    assert bisect_method(a) == counter_method(a) == counter_set_method(a)
    
from random import randint
a = [randint(0, 10**5) for _ in range(10**6)]
assert bisect_method(a) == counter_method(a) == counter_set_method(a)
```

Note:

- Same results up to max(arr) at least until 10**5
- Unknown why counter_set_method becomes different when arr goes to 10**6

**Performance**

- bisect_method (tobias_k) algorithm best performance overall
- counter_set_method close to bisect_method (tobias_k) but becomes better with large arrays
- counter_method worst until large arrays

*Test Code*

```
from random import randint
import numpy as np
import benchit # https://pypi.org/project/benchit/

funcs = [counter_method, counter_set_method, bisect_method]
inputs = [[randint(0, 10**5) for _ in range(x)] for x in 10**np.arange(7)]

t = benchit.timings(funcs, inputs)
print(t)
t.plot(logy=True, logx=True)
```

*Benchmarks*

```
Functions  counter_method  counter_set_method  bisect_method
Len                                                         
1                0.008725            0.000003       0.000001
10               0.035918            0.000008       0.000004
100              0.038195            0.000066       0.000051
1000             0.041830            0.000670       0.000717
10000            0.048070            0.007392       0.009392
100000           0.113914            0.096876       0.144737
1000000          0.708296            0.813105       2.653164
```

[image: Benchmarks]

Comment: Nice, but why `range(max(arr))`? Can't you just do `cnts = {i:0 for i in set(arr)}` or use `Counter`? I think this should be faster if `max >> len`, but might require sorting the values for the aggregation phase, which would make it O(nlogn) instead of O(m)...

Comment: Also, which version of Python are you using? For me it says dict-items are not reversible...

Comment: @tobias_k--version 3.8.3

Comment: Okay, 3.6 on my box. However, I get much different results for a list of 1,000 random numbers up to 100,000: ~550 µs for bisect and 20 ms (!) for counter (collecting the items in a list before reversing) (but only 300 µs for counter with `set`)

Comment: In fact, I just noticed you do `randint(0, 10*6)`, i.e. your `max` is just 60! I guess you meant `10**6`?

Comment: @tobias_k--thanks for the catch on 10*6.  Let me rerun the code.

Comment: Forgot to `sort` the dict-items when using `set`, which gave the wrong result. With `{i:0 for i in sorted(set(arr))} ` and `for k, cnt in reversed(list(cnts.items()))` it's 450 µs

Comment: @tobias_k--does set have to be sorted?  I get the same answer as other solutions without sorting set.

Comment: For me, a set of random numbers _prints_ in sorted order, but when converted to list or dict, the numbers appear in random order, thus messing up the aggregation. Might be different for 3.8, though.

Comment: @tobias_k--updated post.  With Python 3.8 the results are the same till at least max(arr) of 10^5.  With max(arr) of 10^6 get incorrect results for unsorted set.  Wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* compare all pairs of elements, that would be O(n²). Instead, you can sort the list and then use the [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to binary-search the `sorted` array for the correct place to insert the element and get the number of larger elements from that position. Complexity for this is O(nlogn).

```
>>> import bisect
>>> a = [3, 7, 4, 2, 0]
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> [len(a) - bisect.bisect_left(b, x) for x in a]
[3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

(Just `bisect_left(b, x)` would be the place where to insert the element in the sorted list, i.e. the number of elements *smaller* than `x`; since you need the number of elements `x` is smaller-or-equal to, you need `len(a)` minus that.)

This also works for repeated elements and yields the same result as a simple O(n²) approach:

```
>>> a = [3, 7, 4, 2, 0, 4]
>>> b = sorted(a)
>>> [len(a) - bisect.bisect_left(b, x) for x in a]
[4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 3]
>>> [sum(1 for y in a if x<=y) for x in a] # just for reference, do not use this
[4, 1, 3, 5, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple comparisons, you can use the following:

```
b = [sorted(a, reverse=True).index(i)+1 for i in a]
```

Comment: This does not _exclicitly_ do multiple comparisons, but the complexity is even worse than comparing all pairs of elements... also, `index` might not work if the list has repeated elements.